# Getter from Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, swift, getter

How can I recreate this getter code in Swift

```
- (UIPageControl *)pageControl {
    if (!_pageControl) {
        _pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
        _pageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        _pageControl.frame = (CGRect){0, 35, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), 0};
        _pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = YES;
        _pageControl.currentPage = self.currentPage;
        _pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:.5];
    } 
return _pageControl;
}
```

This is what I currently have

```
var pageControl: UIPageControl {
get{
    if (self.pageControl == nil) {
        var pageControl: UIPageControl= UIPageControl.alloc()
        pageControl.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleTopMargin;
        pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), 0)
        pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = true;
        pageControl.currentPage = self.currentPage;
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        return pageControl
    }
    return self.pageControl
}
}
```

But that isn't the same because it isn't setting self.pageControl and if I try add this

```
self.pageControl = pageControl
```

I get this error "cannot assign to 'pageControl' in 'self'"

Comment: and where is your _setter_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property has a getter, so is a 'computed property' as a result it does not have a setter (unless you supply one yourself). I suspect what you want to do is back your computed property with a private stored property:

```
private var _pageControl: UIPageControl?

var pageControl: UIPageControl {
get{
    // if the private backing variable doesn't exist, create it
    if (_pageControl == nil) {
        _pageControl = UIPageControl()
        // ...
    }
    return _pageControl
}
}
```

Alternatively, take a look at [Lazy Stored Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yah! that's the problem with getter in swift, you need to create separate method for to get pageControl.

like

```
func getPageControl() {

    if (self.pageControl == nil) {
        self.pageControl = UIPageControl.alloc()
         self.pageControl.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleTopMargin;
         self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), 0)
         self.pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = true;
         self.pageControl.currentPage = self.currentPage;
         self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)

    }
    return self.pageControl
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this where you only create the control once, you could also use a `lazy` stored property, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
    lazy var pageControl = MyClass.makePageControl()

    private class func makePageControl() -> UIPageControl {
        let pg = UIPageControl()
        pg.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleTopMargin;
        // …
        return pg
    }
}
```